# How can I make this type of outline-type menu?

Tags: css, navigation, menu

I really want to add this kind of expandable outline-type menu to my website. I've seen it before in digital help manuals, but I've never seen one online. Each item would link to a page in my website.

[image: This kind of menu]

The reason why I want this kind of menu rather than a regular dropdown menu or megamenu are:

1. It's more compact.
2. It's more aesthetically pleasing (in my opinion).
3. Almost all the pages of my website are under 3-4 levels of hierarchy, so having this kind of menu would make for fast navigation.

How can I make this type of menu? Preferably the solution would only involve HTML, CSS and Javascript, but I am open to using something else if it would be radically easier.

Thanks!

Comment: "How do I implement something" questions are very broad.   There are generally many ways to implement something.   Please focus your question on something that isn't working rather than "how do I get started".  Coding questions are also better asked at [so].